# Transição de menu lateral com easing

Tags: javascript, rolamento, css-transições

Olá! Eu quero colocar um efeito "easing" pra deixar mais "suave" a transição do menu lateral que recolhe/expande no meu site pois quando clico no botão pra recolher ele apenas recolhe em milésimos de segundo, sem efeito nenhum.

Expandido:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Recolhido:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fiz um exemplo de como está nesse [Site](https://docpay.000webhostapp.com/).

JS:

```
$("#sidebarToggle, #sidebarToggleTop").on('click', function(e) {
$("body").toggleClass("sidebar-toggled");
$(".sidebar").toggleClass("toggled"); }
```

CSS:

```
body.sidebar-toggled footer.sticky-footer {width: 100%;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na sua ul `<ul class="navbar-nav bg-gradient-primary sidebar sidebar-dark accordion" id="accordionSidebar">` coloque `transition: 500ms all;` e vc vai dar uma "atenuada" na transição no recolhimento da side bar como vc pode ver na imagem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado hugocsl! Ajudou muito ;)

Apenas complementando caso alguém queira utilizar, adicione na <ul> um Style, ficando assim: <ul class="navbar-nav bg-gradient-primary sidebar sidebar-dark accordion" id="accordionSidebar" style="transition: 300ms all">

Comment: @RogerWindberg sem problemas meu caro, que bom que resolveu ai, []´s